# How can I install NERDTree without pathogen?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-system, plugin-nerdtree

I have only one plugin at the moment (CtrlP) and I don't want to polute my environment with additional stuff that I'll have to depend on.

So I tried installing NERDTree directly (cloned from git in `.vim/bundle`), but I get error after error, for example I added:

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
```

to `.vimrc` and I got:

```
Error detected while processing VimEnter Auto commands for "*":
E492: Not an editor command: NERDTree`.
```

So I gave up at the end and now I'm using the simple `:edit`.

The thing is - can I manually install NERDTree - or any plugin at all - directly?

Comment: `.vim/bundle` is a pathogen thing. If you already installed CtrlP without pathogen you simply have to do the same for nerdtree.

Comment: With Vim8 simply clone it to `~/.vim/pack/dist/start/nerdtree`

Answer (score 2):

You can either manually do what Pathogen does for you:

```
set runtimepath+=~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree
```

Or, you can go back to the Stone Age and copy everything in that folder to `~/.vim`.